# Эпоха глянцевых журналов

Tags: метафора

Является ли выражение "Эпоха глянцевых журналов" образным? Это метафора или что-то другое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Образ рождает? Да - значит выражение образное. Только это конечно не метафора, эпитет.

Comment: Спасибо, Марк Из!